# ASP.net - Getting table index on html table when button clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-table, mouseclick-event

I have the following code which populates an html table from data retrieved from Parse.com.

As you can see the table has buttons in it which are generated as the table gets populated. When clicked, obviously the buttons need to perform an action related to that row of data.

Can anybody help me with the click event please, specifically getting the row index?

At the moment the click event doesn't even seem to trigger the "response.Write" alert. (i'm very new to asp.net though)

```
using Parse;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace FrogPointCMS
{
    public partial class Beacons : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string merchantName;
        string myMerchantID;
        ParseObject merchantObject;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            merchantName = Request.QueryString["user"];
            myMerchantID = Request.QueryString["merchantID"];

            merchantObject = (ParseObject)Session["Merchant"];

            getBeacons();


        }

        public async void getBeacons()
        {
             MyParseQueries myQuery = new MyParseQueries();

             var myBeacons = await myQuery.getMyBeacons(merchantObject);

            foreach (ParseObject beacon in myBeacons)
            {
                string aliasName = "";
                string offerType = "N/A";
                string offerTitle = "";
                string offerDescription = "";

                 var merchantOb = beacon.Get<ParseObject>("merchantObjectId");
                 var merchantID = merchantOb.ObjectId;

                 if (merchantID == myMerchantID)
                 {
                     if (beacon.ContainsKey("contentObjectID"))
                     {
                         ParseObject content = beacon.Get<ParseObject>("contentObjectID"); // get the content object from parse.
                         offerType = content.Get<string>("offerType");
                         offerTitle = content.Get<string>("offerTitle");
                         offerDescription = content.Get<string>("offerDescription");
                     }

                     aliasName = beacon.Get<string>("aliasName");

                     Button assignNameBtn = new Button();
                     assignNameBtn.ID = "assignName";
                     assignNameBtn.Text = "Assign Name";
                     assignNameBtn.Click += assignNameBtn_Click;

                     Button assignActionBtn = new Button();
                     assignActionBtn.ID = "assignAction";
                     assignActionBtn.Text = "Assign Action";

                     var tr = new HtmlTableRow();
                     var checkBox = new HtmlTableCell();
                     var tableCellName = new HtmlTableCell();
                     var tableCellButton1 = new HtmlTableCell();
                     var tableCellButton2 = new HtmlTableCell();
                     var tableCellAction = new HtmlTableCell();

                     checkBox.InnerHtml = "<input  type=\"checkbox\"/>";
                     tableCellName.InnerText = aliasName;
                     tableCellButton1.Controls.Add(assignNameBtn);
                     tableCellButton2.Controls.Add(assignActionBtn);
                     tableCellAction.InnerText = offerType + " - " + offerTitle + " - " + offerDescription;

                     tr.Cells.Add(checkBox);
                     tr.Cells.Add(tableCellName);
                     tr.Cells.Add(tableCellButton1);
                     tr.Cells.Add(tableCellAction);
                     tr.Cells.Add(tableCellButton2);

                     beaconTable.Rows.Add(tr);
                 }

            }

        }

        void assignNameBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Button clicked');</script>");

            var btn = (Button)sender; // testing 

            HtmlTableRow row = (HtmlTableRow)btn.NamingContainer; //testing


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not use `Response.Write` to append things to the DOM. Instead, for HTML manipulate the control tree. For JavaScript, use [RegisterStartupScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do javascript stuff when clicking a button, use OnClientClick

```
Button b = new Button();
b.OnClientClick = "FunctionName"
```

And then in the html

```
<script>
    function FunctionName() {
        alert('Button clicked');
    }

</script>
```

Comment: OK thanks. I'll bear that it mind. But any pointers on the main issue?

Comment: Getting an id value when clicking the button?

Comment: Yes that's what I need to know please.

Comment: You'll want to have the id in the html somewhere, a hiddenField would be good for this. If you keep your Id values in hidden fields you can get at them in both javascript/C#